# Cloning an Object in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

What is the best way to clone an object in node.js

e.g. I want to avoid the situation where:

```
var obj1 = {x: 5, y:5};
var obj2 = obj1;
obj2.x = 6;
console.log(obj1.x); // logs 6
```

The object may well contain complex types as attributes, so a simple for(var x in obj1) wouldn't solve.  Do I need to write a recursive clone myself or is there something built in that I'm not seeing?

Comment: 1. `npm install underscore` 2. `var _ = require('underscore')` 3. `_.clone(objToClone)`;

Comment: Note that in in @SalmanPK's comment above, this is a **shallow** clone. so it will work for slifty's example, but if there are nested arrays or objects, they'll be references. :/

Comment: I found this article very helpful:  http://heyjavascript.com/4-creative-ways-to-clone-objects/

Comment: @Jordan Hudson - Very nice use of JSON in the second example.

    var newObj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(oldObj));
    //Now newObj is a clone.  

Only problem is that stringify will not work on recursive reference so need to be careful.

Answer (score 334, accepted):

### Possibility 1

Low-frills deep copy:

```
var obj2 = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj1));
```

### Possibility 2 (deprecated)

**Attention:** This solution is now marked as deprecated in the [documentation of Node.js](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_extend_target_source):

> The util._extend() method was never intended to be used outside of internal Node.js modules. The community found and used it anyway.
>
> It is deprecated and should not be used in new code. JavaScript comes with very similar built-in functionality through Object.assign().

**Original answer:**:

For a shallow copy, use Node's built-in `util._extend()` function.

```
var extend = require('util')._extend;

var obj1 = {x: 5, y:5};
var obj2 = extend({}, obj1);
obj2.x = 6;
console.log(obj1.x); // still logs 5
```

Source code of Node's `_extend` function is in here: https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/lib/util.js

```
exports._extend = function(origin, add) {
  // Don't do anything if add isn't an object
  if (!add || typeof add !== 'object') return origin;

  var keys = Object.keys(add);
  var i = keys.length;
  while (i--) {
    origin[keys[i]] = add[keys[i]];
  }
  return origin;
};
```

Comment: The question specifically called for a recursive clone. This is a shallow clone.

Comment: Isn't a name like `_*` supposed to mean it's a private method and should not be relied upon?

Comment: Every JavaScript project of any size has one or more implementations of extend(), and Node is no exception. The Node.js core makes extensive use of this function. To quote Isaacs, ["It's not going anywhere any time soon."](https://github.com/joyent/node/pull/4834#issuecomment-13981250)

Comment: worked perfectly for me.  much better than messing about with Object prototype imo

Comment: I *wish* this worked, it would have been awesome. But you have not avoided the pass-by-reference problem in which the author initially asked.

Comment: @netpoetica: It worked for me, nested objects were not copied as references. Just commenting for anyone else who reads this comments...

Comment: @AaronStorck, I think you are mistaken. Consider the following code: `var obj = {arr:[1]};
var copy = _extend(obj);
obj.arr.push(2);`. At the end of this code, both `obj` and `copy` contain the array `[1,2]`, not just `copy` as would be the case with a real clone.

Comment: Properly deep-copying an object is a little more involved; I included such a function in my [simpleoo](https://github.com/mbrowne/simpleoo.js) library, and I also posted the function here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13333781/560114

Comment: Originally my answer lacked a deep-copy option. So I added one that I use frequently.

Comment: This is the WRONG answer. As per node's documentation:

https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_extend_obj

_The `util._extend()` method was never intended to be used outside of internal Node.js modules. The community found and used it anyway._

_**It is deprecated and should not be used in new code.** JavaScript comes with very similar built-in functionality through `Object.assign().`_

Comment: Using JSON will fail, incase the object contains ANSI escape codes.

Comment: This merges the add keys in to the origin object.  It still returns the same updated origin object.  How is that a clone?

Comment: @Phil_1984_ Typical use of `_extend()` is to pass a new empty object that gets returned. This becomes the shallow clone. You can also use `_extend()` just to copy properties.

Comment: This is just my opinion, but rather than augmenting the "typical pattern" of `_extend` for something similar but semantically different from extending, wouldn't it be better to write e.g. `exports._clone = function(toClone) { return exports._extend({}, toClone); }` It just seems like you are advocating using an axe to hammer in a nail.

Comment: The `var obj2 = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj1));` solution was perfect for my need. Thanks for sharing this.

Comment: JSON method is the right way even if deprecated.  Assign is just for shallow clone which is a bad way. [Warning for Deep Clone](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign#Deep_Clone). If the object can be stringified, it is better to stick with `json`.

Comment: Circular Reference Error. Object.assign({}, source) is the best solution

Answer (score 312):

### For a **SHALLOW** copy:

I'm surprised `Object.assign` hasn't been mentioned.

```
let cloned = Object.assign({}, source); // SHALLOW copy
```

If available (e.g. Babel), you can use the [object spread operator](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-object-rest-spread):

```
let cloned = { ... source };
```

Comment: this is a much better solution than having to import a third-party library or use the imperfect JSON workaround. Thanks!

Comment: this is a shallow copy

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign

Cloning an object

Comment: If anyone's wondering, this is how you clone an array: clone = arr.slice(0)

Comment: Warning for Deep Clone, For deep clone still need to use other alternatives. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign#Deep_Clone

Comment: This definitely is the most elegant answer, thank you very much!

Comment: From what I can tell the object spread operator is not an ES6 thing but instead a stage 3 proposal. which means you can use it with babel but not without from what I understand. https://github.com/tc39/proposal-object-rest-spread#status-of-this-proposal

Comment: @macdja38 You're right, I updated my answer, thank you.

Comment: Object.assign does a shallow copy. look at this article: https://scotch.io/bar-talk/copying-objects-in-javascript

Comment: Checking with node10: it does not sound like a cloned object. Using `const a = { a: 1, b: 2 }; const b = Object.assign(a, { b: 42 }); console.log(a); console.log(b);`. Both `b` and `a` would include my modification.

Comment: Furthermore, assign() will copy functions not JSON trick.
let o= Object.assign({}, {logit:(m)=>console.log(m)});
console.log(o);
console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(o)));

Comment: Much better answer than the accepted one.

Answer (score 24):

```
Object.defineProperty(Object.prototype, "extend", {
    enumerable: false,
    value: function(from) {
        var props = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(from);
        var dest = this;
        props.forEach(function(name) {
            if (name in dest) {
                var destination = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(from, name);
                Object.defineProperty(dest, name, destination);
            }
        });
        return this;
    }
});
```

This will define an extend method that you can use. Code comes [from this article.](http://onemoredigit.com/post/1527191998/extending-objects-in-node-js)

Comment: I don't see how this is supposed to work.  It modifies the original Object!  How am I supposed to use this function to get a clone of an object?  Can you add some usage code here?  After reading your post and the blog post, I still can't figure out how this is intended to be used for cloning an object.

Comment: does this really work? "if (name in dest)" - will only change the property if it already exists in dest. it should be negated.

Comment: Isn't modifying Object.prototype supposed to be verboten? Also that article link is broken.

Comment: Just tried the article link and it works for me. Maybe it was a network blip when you tried it.

Comment: Based on a number of comments, I've updated the answer to include a variant that does not add to object's prototype.

Answer (score 20):

```
var obj2 = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj1));
```

Comment: This was already suggested in [this existing answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7131327/447356) no point repeating it.

Comment: @ShadowWizard these are different methods. This one simply converts to json and back to object, while linked answer uses `Object.keys()` to iterate through object

Comment: This answer is wrong. JSON.stringify takes a date object and reduces it to a string, and then after parsing it leaves it as a string so it mutates the state of your object leaving you with a different object than initially in case of dates.

Comment: Further to @twboc, object properties that are explicitly undefined will not be copied using this method.

Answer (score 13):

You can use the extend function from JQuery:

```
var newClone= jQuery.extend({}, oldObject);  
var deepClone = jQuery.extend(true, {}, oldObject);
```

There is a Node.js Plugin too:

https://github.com/shimondoodkin/nodejs-clone-extend

To do it without JQuery or Plugin read this here:

http://my.opera.com/GreyWyvern/blog/show.dml/1725165

Comment: To post a jQuery solution for NODE is rather dumb!
At least you could have extracted the code and offer a node solution in here, but too lazy!

Answer (score 12):

Check out [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org). It has both [clone](http://underscorejs.org/#clone) and [extend](http://underscorejs.org/#extend) and many other very useful functions.

This can be useful: [Using the Underscore module with Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5691901/using-the-underscore-module-with-node-js)

Answer (score 9):

There are some Node modules out there if don't want to "roll your own". This one looks good: https://www.npmjs.com/package/clone

Looks like it handles all kinds of stuff, including circular references. From the [github](https://github.com/pvorb/node-clone) page:

> clone masters cloning objects, arrays, Date objects, and RegEx
>   objects. Everything is cloned recursively, so that you can clone dates
>   in arrays in objects, for example. [...] Circular references? Yep!

Answer (score 7):

There is another library [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs), it has [clone](https://lodash.com/docs#clone) and [cloneDeep](https://lodash.com/docs#cloneDeep).

`clone` will clone your object but not create a new instance for non-primitive values, instead it will use the referrence to the original object

`cloneDeep` will create literally new objects without having any referrence to the original object, so it more safe when you have to change the object afterwards.

Answer (score 7):

This code is also work cause The **Object.create()** method creates a new object with the specified prototype object and properties.

```
var obj1 = {x:5, y:5};

var obj2 = Object.create(obj1);

obj2.x; //5
obj2.x = 6;
obj2.x; //6

obj1.x; //5
```

Comment: this is a shallow copy

Comment: Additionally, while this works fine with an object created via an _object literal_, it doesn't when cloning something like `process.env`:  While direct property access on the clone works, _reflecting on it_ doesn't; e.g.
`let clone = Object.create(process.env); JSON.stringify(clone); Reflect.ownKeys(c)` yields `'{}'` and `[]`

Answer (score 5):

Simple and the fastest way to clone an Object in NodeJS is to use Object.keys( obj ) method

```
var a = {"a": "a11", "b": "avc"};
var b;

for(var keys = Object.keys(a), l = keys.length; l; --l)
{
   b[ keys[l-1] ] = a[ keys[l-1] ];
}
b.a = 0;

console.log("a: " + JSON.stringify(a)); // LOG: a: {"a":"a11","b":"avc"} 
console.log("b: " + JSON.stringify(b)); // LOG: b: {"a":0,"b":"avc"}
```

The method Object.keys requires JavaScript 1.8.5; nodeJS v0.4.11 supports this method

but of course for nested objects need to implement recursive func

---

Other solution is to use native JSON (Implemented in JavaScript 1.7), but it's much slower (~10 times slower) than previous one

```
var a = {"a": i, "b": i*i};
var b = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(a));
b.a = 0;
```

Answer (score 5):

There is also a project on Github that aims to be a more direct port of the `jQuery.extend()`:

https://github.com/dreamerslab/node.extend

An example, modified from the [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/):

```
var extend = require('node.extend');

var object1 = {
    apple: 0,
    banana: {
        weight: 52,
        price: 100
    },
    cherry: 97
};

var object2 = {
    banana: {
        price: 200
    },
    durian: 100
};

var merged = extend(object1, object2);
```

Answer (score 5):

All modern browsers and Node V17+ support the global [`structuredClone()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/structuredClone) function:

```js
const obj2 = structuredClone(obj1);
```

Comment: Looks like a modern solution.

Answer (score 4):

Looking for a true clone option, I stumbled across ridcully's link to here:

http://my.opera.com/GreyWyvern/blog/show.dml/1725165

I modified the solution on that page so that the function attached to the `Object` prototype is not enumerable.  Here is my result:

```
Object.defineProperty(Object.prototype, 'clone', {
    enumerable: false,
    value: function() {
        var newObj = (this instanceof Array) ? [] : {};
        for (i in this) {
        if (i == 'clone') continue;
            if (this[i] && typeof this[i] == "object") {
                newObj[i] = this[i].clone();
            } else newObj[i] = this[i]
        } return newObj;
    }
});
```

Hopefully this helps someone else as well.  Note that there are some caveats... particularly with properties named "clone".  This works well for me.  I don't take any credit for writing it.  Again, I only changed how it was being defined.

Comment: This is wrong. Dates type is object so this code would replace dates by empty objects... Don't use this.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use SugarJS in NodeJS.

http://sugarjs.com/

They have a very clean clone feature:
http://sugarjs.com/api/Object/clone

Answer (score 0):

None of the answers satisfied me, several don't work or are just shallow clones, answers from @clint-harris and using JSON.parse/stringify are good but quite slow. I found a module that does deep cloning fast: https://github.com/AlexeyKupershtokh/node-v8-clone

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in way to do a real clone (deep copy) of an object in node.js. There are some tricky edge cases so you should definitely use a library for this. I wrote such a function for my [simpleoo](https://github.com/mbrowne/simpleoo.js) library. You can use the `deepCopy` function without using anything else from the library (which is quite small) if you don't need it. This function supports cloning multiple data types, including arrays, dates, and regular expressions, it supports recursive references, and it also works with objects whose constructor functions have required parameters.

Here is the code:

```
//If Object.create isn't already defined, we just do the simple shim, without the second argument,
//since that's all we need here
var object_create = Object.create;
if (typeof object_create !== 'function') {
    object_create = function(o) {
        function F() {}
        F.prototype = o;
        return new F();
    };
}

/**
 * Deep copy an object (make copies of all its object properties, sub-properties, etc.)
 * An improved version of http://keithdevens.com/weblog/archive/2007/Jun/07/javascript.clone
 * that doesn't break if the constructor has required parameters
 * 
 * It also borrows some code from http://stackoverflow.com/a/11621004/560114
 */ 
function deepCopy = function deepCopy(src, /* INTERNAL */ _visited) {
    if(src == null || typeof(src) !== 'object'){
        return src;
    }

    // Initialize the visited objects array if needed
    // This is used to detect cyclic references
    if (_visited == undefined){
        _visited = [];
    }
    // Ensure src has not already been visited
    else {
        var i, len = _visited.length;
        for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            // If src was already visited, don't try to copy it, just return the reference
            if (src === _visited[i]) {
                return src;
            }
        }
    }

    // Add this object to the visited array
    _visited.push(src);

    //Honor native/custom clone methods
    if(typeof src.clone == 'function'){
        return src.clone(true);
    }

    //Special cases:
    //Array
    if (Object.prototype.toString.call(src) == '[object Array]') {
        //[].slice(0) would soft clone
        ret = src.slice();
        var i = ret.length;
        while (i--){
            ret[i] = deepCopy(ret[i], _visited);
        }
        return ret;
    }
    //Date
    if (src instanceof Date) {
        return new Date(src.getTime());
    }
    //RegExp
    if (src instanceof RegExp) {
        return new RegExp(src);
    }
    //DOM Element
    if (src.nodeType && typeof src.cloneNode == 'function') {
        return src.cloneNode(true);
    }

    //If we've reached here, we have a regular object, array, or function

    //make sure the returned object has the same prototype as the original
    var proto = (Object.getPrototypeOf ? Object.getPrototypeOf(src): src.__proto__);
    if (!proto) {
        proto = src.constructor.prototype; //this line would probably only be reached by very old browsers 
    }
    var ret = object_create(proto);

    for(var key in src){
        //Note: this does NOT preserve ES5 property attributes like 'writable', 'enumerable', etc.
        //For an example of how this could be modified to do so, see the singleMixin() function
        ret[key] = deepCopy(src[key], _visited);
    }
    return ret;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this **[clone](https://www.npmjs.com/package/clone)** library to deep clone objects.

```
 npm install --save clone
```

```
const clone = require('clone');

const clonedObject = clone(sourceObject);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're working with ordinary objects and arrays, and don't care about cloning functions or recursive references, here's a simple `deepClone` implementation which works on ordinary objects, arrays, strings, numbers, regex, dates, etc.

```js
// Simple Deep Clone
// Does not clone functions or handle recursive references.
function deepClone(original) {
  if (original instanceof RegExp) {
    return new RegExp(original);
  } else if (original instanceof Date) {
    return new Date(original.getTime());
  } else if (Array.isArray(original)) {
    return original.map(deepClone);
  } else if (typeof original === 'object' && original !== null) {
    const clone = {};
    Object.keys(original).forEach(k => {
      clone[k] = deepClone(original[k]);
    });
    return clone;
  }
  return original;
}

// Usage:

const obj = { n: 1, a: [ { a: 1 }, { a: 2 } ], d: new Date(), s: 'foo' };
const clone = deepClone(obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

Good article about this problem: https://www.samanthaming.com/tidbits/70-3-ways-to-clone-objects/

```
var obj1 = {x: 5, y:5};
var obj2 = Object.assign({}, obj1 );
    
obj2  = {z: 10};
    
console.log(obj1);
console.log(obj2);
```

Answer (score -1):

Another solution is to encapsulate directly in the new variable using: 
`obj1= {...obj2}`

Comment: This is a shallow copy

Answer (score -2):

If you're using coffee-script, it's as easy as:

```
newObject = {}
newObject[key] = value  for own key,value of oldObject
```

Though this isn't a deep clone.

Comment: ...but the OP isn't using CoffeeScript... how is this relevant?!

Comment: this is just a LAME answer - totally useless. The question was about pure NODE not crappy script

Answer (score -2):

You can prototype object and then call object instance every time you want to use and change object:

```
function object () {
  this.x = 5;
  this.y = 5;
}
var obj1 = new object();
var obj2 = new object();
obj2.x = 6;
console.log(obj1.x); //logs 5
```

You can also pass arguments to object constructor

```
function object (x, y) {
   this.x = x;
   this.y = y;
}
var obj1 = new object(5, 5);
var obj2 = new object(6, 6);
console.log(obj1.x); //logs 5
console.log(obj2.x); //logs 6
```

Hope this is helpful.