# Changing Node.js' REPL return value from underscore _ to something else?

Tags: javascript, node.js, underscore.js, read-eval-print-loop

Related question: [Using the Underscore module with Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5691901/using-the-underscore-module-with-node-js)

Is there a way to change the variable Node.js' [REPL](http://nodejs.org/api/repl.html#repl_repl_features) sets the last return value to? If you could change it from `_` to `__` or `$_`, you could then globalize the underscore module so you don't have to set it to a variable in every file: https://gist.github.com/3220108

Comment: If you did this, wouldn't you potentially break modules that are using the underscore for the native REPL? If you want to set a global for underscore, why not use a value that's not already defined in Node, such as the double underscore or $_ as you suggest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can change `_` unless you want to edit the source. The node.js REPL appears to be implemented in [`lib/repl.js`](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/v0.8.4-release/lib/repl.js); if you poke around the library a little bit, you'll see things [like this](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/v0.8.4-release/lib/repl.js#L231):

```
self.context._ = self.context[cmd] = lib;
self.outputStream.write(self.writer(lib) + '\n');
```

and [like this](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/v0.8.4-release/lib/repl.js#L308):

```
self.context._ = ret;
self.outputStream.write(self.writer(ret) + '\n');
```

The `self.context` object is the REPL's global context or namespace (similar to `window` in a browser) so `self.context._ = ret;` is equivalent to saying `_ = ret` from the REPL's prompt.

So `_` is hardwired and there's nothing you can do about it unless you want to hack the node.js libraries.

Answer (score 3):

I figured out a way to do this using the native Node `repl` module. Instead of just running `node` at the command line, put this in something like `console.js` and then run `node console.js`:

```
var repl = require('repl')
var vm = require('vm');

var _;

var server = repl.start({
  eval: function (cmd, context, filename, callback) {
    try {
      var match = cmd.match(/^\((.*)\n\)$/);
      var code = match ? match[1] : cmd;
      context._ = _;
      var result = vm.runInThisContext(code, filename);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error.stack);
    } finally {
      _ = context._;
      callback(null, result);
    }
  }
}).on('exit', function () {
  process.exit(0);
});
```

Here's a Gist: https://gist.github.com/jasoncrawford/6818650