# In the Node.js REPL, why does this happen?

Tags: node.js, underscore.js, read-eval-print-loop

So I was playing around with the Node.js REPL and the Underscore library when I noticed something very strange. If I `require("underscore")`, the variable `_` is set globally (obviously). Then when I attempt to run a simple command like `console.log(_.isEmpty)` it prints `[Function]` (again, obviously). However, upon running `console.log(_)` right after, it prints `[Function]` because the variable `_` was set to `_.isEmpty`.

Why does this do this? If I run the same code from a js file this doesn't happen. Is this a normal Node thing or is this a total bug?

FYI: Node v0.10.10

Comment: See also [Using the Underscore module with Node.js](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5691901/1048572)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Node's REPL always sets `_` to the result of the last line.

```
> 2
2
> _
2
> 2+2
4
> _
4
>
```

You need to use a different identifier:

```
var u = require("underscore");
u.isEmpty
```

Comment: So use underscore `.noConflict()` mode

Comment: Wow had I just read the full documentation I would have figured that out. Thanks! Guess I'm not just crazy...

Comment: With Node v6.0, the default behavior of `_` (underscore) is disabled when it is assigned to any value. A message shows "Expression assignment to _ now disabled."