# What does the "_" (underscore) symbol in Node.js REPL mean?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I was playing in Node.js with some code when I noticed this thing:

```
> 'hello world'.padEnd(20);
'hello world         '
> 'hello world'.padEnd(20, _);
'hello worldhello wor'
```

What does the underscore symbol do here?

```
> _
'hello worldhello wor'
```

Comment: https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/repl.html#repl_assignment_of_the_underscore_variable

Comment: See also [In the Node.js REPL, why does this happen?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17073290/1048572)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`_` symbol returns the result of the last logged expression in REPL node console:

```
> 2 * 2
4
> _
4
```

As written in [documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/repl.html#repl_assignment_of_the_underscore_variable), in 6.x and higher versions of node this behavior can be disabled by setting value to `_` explicitly:

```
> [ 'a', 'b', 'c' ]
[ 'a', 'b', 'c' ]
> _.length
3
> _ += 1
Expression assignment to _ now disabled.
4
> 1 + 1
2
> _
4
```

But in older versions that feature doesn't work:

```
> [ 'a', 'b', 'c' ]
[ 'a', 'b', 'c' ]
> _.length
3
> _ += 1
4
> 1 + 1
2
> _
2
```

Answer (score 29):

`_` in the node console returns the result of the last expression.

```
> 1 + 2
3
> _
3
```

Comment: Wow, what a wildly unexpected behavior.

Comment: This happens ***only*** in the REPL (interactive console), and it is [fully documented](https://nodejs.org/api/repl.html#repl_assignment_of_the_underscore_variable).  In normal code, the underscore is just another variable identifier.

Comment: @canon, I once had a professor who, after filling a board with equations, said "and so  obviously-" and began filling a second board.  I held up my hand.  "Dr. Goldman, are you sure it's obvious?"  This stopped him.  He stared silent at his own work for a good minute.  "Yes," he concluded.  "It's obvious."  When I saw this question in the sidebar, I thought, "It probably means the result of the last expression."

Comment: This is not wildly unexpected-- in fact, it's not even unique to node.js or even JavaScript. It's in Python and Ruby interactive environments and probably even more languages that I haven't used.

Comment: @YetAnotherUser I think this might have originated with Perl.

Comment: "This is not wildly unexpected" - all sigils are wildly unexpected.  For example, if instead it were `__previousResult__` then this question never would have been asked.