# Node.js cannot require and assign lodash to a variable named underscore (_)

Tags: node.js, lodash

I am trying to use lodash in a Node.js project. If I require the module using the following statement, it works fine:

```
var lodash = require("lodash");
```

However, if I change the statement to something like this:

```
var _ = require("lodash");
```

then the variable underscore `_` is undefined. Not sure why this is happening and also could not find anything online regarding this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5691901/using-the-underscore-module-with-node-js

Comment: this code `var _ = require("lodash");` works well in my project...

Comment: @MukeshSharma, I'm facing the same issue. Were you able to solve this?