# Clone a function in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Cloning an Object in Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5055746/cloning-an-object-in-node-js)

I want to clone a Cheerio function object, but am having problems using the regular methods.

So, say the object is `$object`, I have tried to clone it doing:

```
eval("var clone = " + $object.toString());
```

But then I get this error message:

```
var clone = [object Function]
```

Here's the output of the original `$object`

```
{ [Function: initialize]
  _root: 
   { type: 'root',
     name: 'root',
     parent: null,
     prev: null,
     next: null,
     children: [] } }
```

So, does anyone know how I can clone this thing (in a fast way?)

Comment: See this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5055746/cloning-an-object-in-node-js

Comment: `Object.toString()` does not return the source code for the function, i think firefox has `Object.toSource()` which would do that, but its not a standard function. Best to use something like what @Niels suggested

Comment: Use cheerio's .clone() method: https://cheerio.js.org#clone