# Combine or merge JSON on node.js without jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, node.js

I have multiple `JSON` like those

```
var object1 = {name: "John"};
var object2 = {location: "San Jose"};
```

They are not nesting or anything like that. Just basically different fields. I need to combine them into one single `JSON` in **node.js** like this:

```
{name: "John", location: "San Jose"}
```

I can use **jQuery** just fine. Here is a working example in the browser:

http://jsfiddle.net/qhoc/agp54/

But if I do this in **node.js**, I don't want to load jQuery (which is a bit over use, plus **node.js' jQuery** doesn't work on my *Windows* machine).

So is there a simple way to do things similar to `$.extend()` without **jQuery**?

Comment: If you're doing various things like this, you might want to consider using [Underscore](http://underscorejs.org/#extend), which is available as a [Node module](https://npmjs.org/package/underscore).

Comment: `npm install extend`, [Port of jQuery.extend for Node.js](https://github.com/justmoon/node-extend).

Comment: FYI  Object.assign does this, but unfortunately it's not currently supported. Hopefully someday soon!
 https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign

Comment: That's not JSON, you're just creating standard JS objects using literal notation. (E.g. in JSON keys must be strings).  And when you're 'combining' those object it has zero to do with JSON.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

A normal loop?

```
function extend(target) {
    var sources = [].slice.call(arguments, 1);
    sources.forEach(function (source) {
        for (var prop in source) {
            target[prop] = source[prop];
        }
    });
    return target;
}

var object3 = extend({}, object1, object2);
```

That's a basic starting point. You may want to add things like a `hasOwnProperty` check, or add some logic to handle the case where multiple source objects have a property with the same identifier.

Here's a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/2jZz3/).

*Side note*: what you are referring to as "JSON" are actually normal JavaScript objects. JSON is simply a text format that shares some syntax with JavaScript.

Comment: I use this function to merge two json. But the reultant json is prefexed with '0'. Example 0 : {kye : value}. Please help me how do i prefix with my own string instead of '0'?

Comment: Down voted cause this is one of the cases where people, especially newbies, should be directed to tested libraries.

Comment: @James I'm a newbie to react. your solution says it is taking 3 arguments where as one is expected for extend. Please suggest what change I need to make.

Comment: @vinny don't use this, please; why is this still marked as correct answer?

Answer (score 147):

### You should use "[Object.assign()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)"

There's no need to reinvent the wheel for such a simple use case of shallow merging.

> The Object.assign() method is used to copy the values of all enumerable own properties from one or more source objects to a target object. It will return the target object.

```js
var o1 = { a: 1 };
var o2 = { b: 2 };
var o3 = { c: 3 };

var obj = Object.assign(o1, o2, o3);
console.log(obj);       // { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 }
console.log(o1);        // { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 }, target object itself is changed
console.log(obj === o1) // true
```

Even the folks from [Node.js say so](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_extend_target_source):

> `_extend` was never intended to be used outside of internal NodeJS modules. The community found and used it anyway.
> It is deprecated and should not be used in new code. JavaScript comes with very similar built-in functionality through `Object.assign`.

---

#### Update:

### You could use the [*spread operator*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

Since [version 8.6](https://node.green/#ES2018-features-object-rest-spread-properties-object-spread-properties), it's possible to natively use the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) in Node.js. Example below:

```js
let o1 = { a: 1 };
let o2 = { b: 2 };
let obj = { ...o1, ...o2 }; // { a: 1, b: 2 }
```

`Object.assign` still works, though.

---

**PS1**: If you are actually interested in **deep merging** (in which internal object data -- in any depth -- is recursively merged), you can use packages like [deepmerge](https://www.npmjs.com/package/deepmerge), [assign-deep](https://www.npmjs.com/package/assign-deep) or [lodash.merge](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash.merge), which are pretty small and simple to use.

**PS2**: Keep in mind that *Object.assign doesn't work with 0.X versions of Node.js*. If you are working with one of those versions (*you really shouldn't by now*), you could use `require("util")._extend` as shown in the Node.js link above -- for more details, check [tobymackenzie's answer to this same question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22286375/36272).

Comment: +1 To anyone coming here looking for a native _browser_ alternative, note this is an ES6 feature and as such [not well supported yet](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign).

Comment: Adding to [Boaz](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1889273/boaz) comment, in the Mozilla link for `Object.assign` above, you can find a polyfill that works just fine in a browser.

Comment: Call it with an empty first argument to avoid accidentally mangling your objects: `var obj = Object.assign({}, o1, o2, o3)`

Answer (score 58):

If using Node version >= 4, use `Object.assign()` (see [Ricardo Nolde's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37336592/1139122)).

If using Node 0.x, there is the built in util._extend:

```
var extend = require('util')._extend
var o = extend({}, {name: "John"});
extend(o,  {location: "San Jose"});
```

It doesn't do a deep copy and only allows two arguments at a time, but is built in.  I saw this mentioned on a question about cloning objects in node: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15040626.

If you're concerned about using a "private" method, you could always proxy it:

```
// myutil.js
exports.extend = require('util')._extend;
```

and replace it with your own implementation if it ever disappears.  This is (approximately) their implementation:

```
exports.extend = function(origin, add) {
    if (!add || (typeof add !== 'object' && add !== null)){
        return origin;
    }

    var keys = Object.keys(add);
    var i = keys.length;
    while(i--){
        origin[keys[i]] = add[keys[i]];
    }
    return origin;
};
```

Comment: The underscore in _extend represents a private method, meaning it is not intended for public use.  Not only is this method undocumented, but the implementation could change in any revision, affecting your project.

Comment: As @jimbojw mentioned in a comment on the linked answer, Isaacs says ["You can go ahead and use `util._extends()` … It's not going anywhere any time soon"](https://github.com/joyent/node/pull/4834#issuecomment-13981250).  There is further discussion in that thread.  If you are worried, read through and make a decision for your project.

Comment: npm install util-extend

Comment: the `_extend()` function has beeen deprecated in favor of `Object.Assign()` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign

Answer (score 51):

[Underscore's `extend`](http://underscorejs.org/#extend) is the easiest and quickest way to achieve this, like James commented.

Here's an example using underscore:

```
var _ = require('underscore'), // npm install underscore to install
  object1 = {name: "John"},
  object2 = {location: "San Jose"};

var target = _.extend(object1, object2);
```

object 1 will get the properties of object2 and be returned and assigned to target.
You could do it like this as well, depending on whether you mind object1 being modified:

```
var target = {};
_.extend(target, object1, object2);
```

Comment: Thanks. But like to avoid underscore in node.js too if I can.

Comment: I just have a light node.js app with just express and mailjs. Just don't want to load with other libs if I only use one function. Ur idea is still cool though. Thanks.

Comment: Beware, underscore's extend is only at first level. It cannot merge subojects.

Answer (score 15):

Use [merge](http://goo.gl/cVu0ev).

```
$ npm install merge
```

Sample code:

```
var merge = require('merge'), // npm install -g merge
    original, cloned;

console.log(

    merge({ one: 'hello' }, { two: 'world' })

); // {"one": "hello", "two": "world"}

original = { x: { y: 1 } };

cloned = merge(true, original);

cloned.x.y++;

console.log(original.x.y, cloned.x.y); // 1, 2
```

Answer (score 12):

I see that this thread is too old, but I put my answer here just in logging purposes.

> In one of the comments above you mentioned that you wanted to use
>   'express' in your project which has 'connect' library in the
>   dependency list. Actually 'connect.utils' library contains a 'merge'
>   method that does the trick. So you can use the 3rd party
>   implementation without adding any new 3rd party libraries.

Answer (score 11):

Here is simple solution, to merge JSON.
I did the following.

- Convert each of the JSON to strings using `JSON.stringify(object)`.
- Concatenate all the JSON strings using `+` operator.
- Replace the pattern `/}{/g` with `","`
- Parse the result string back to JSON object

  ```
  var object1 = {name: "John"};
  var object2 = {location: "San Jose"};
  var merged_object = JSON.parse((JSON.stringify(object1) + JSON.stringify(object2)).replace(/}{/g,","))
  ```

The resulting merged JSON will be

```
{name: "John", location: "San Jose"}
```

Comment: Would this work if there is { or } inside the double quote (value)? I am always hesitate to hack string.

Comment: @HP.Yes it will work. This is pretty straight forward simple regex /}{/, no need to worry about string manipulation. :-)

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work if `object2 = {}` since the final characters to be parsed are `,}`. Can be solved by adding, after the replace: `.replace(/,}^/, '}')`

Comment: Use any number of arguments, no matter if any one is empty with http://gist.github.com/rxaviers/6734630

Comment: Props to @RafaelXavier His gist turns this answer into a usable function.

Comment: Please, by advised this doesn't handle deeply JSON merge. Explanation and solution for deep merge here: https://gist.github.com/rxaviers/6734630/#comment-943271 (also commented here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14974864/combine-or-merge-json-on-node-js-without-jquery/14974931#comment28268748_14974931)

Comment: This is an interesting way of doing it. But please don't do this in production. Its difficult to understand and requires the reasonably expensive operations of stringifying and parsing multiple objects. Use a library.

Comment: This wouldn't work in many special cases. And also it's a bad decision to convert objects to strings and convert them back after modification. If you need to modify objects, work with objects.

Answer (score 5):

There is an easy way of doing it in Node.js

```
var object1 = {name: "John"};
var object2 = {location: "San Jose"};
```

To combine/extend this we can use `...` operator in ECMA6

```js
var object1 = {name: "John"};
var object2 = {location: "San Jose"};

var result = {
  ...object1,
  ...object2
}

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 4):

Use spread operator. It is supported in Node since version 8.6

```js
const object1 = {name: "John"};
const object2 = {location: "San Jose"};

const obj = {...object1, ...object2}

console.log(obj)
//   {
//     "name": "John",
//     "location": "San Jose"
//   }
```

Comment: Hi Khaled, you should try to explain what the spread operator does as this will improve your post. Explanations are far better than just stating code. It is also a duplicate of answer already posted.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use this lightweight npm package called [absorb](https://www.npmjs.com/package/absorb)

It is 27 lines of code, 1kb and uses recursion to perform deep object merges.

```
var absorb = require('absorb');
var obj1, obj2;

obj1 = { foo: 123, bar: 456 };
obj2 = { bar: 123, key: 'value' }

absorb(obj1, obj2);

console.log(obj1); // Output: { foo: 123, bar: 123, key: 'value' }
```

You can also use it to make a clone or only transfer values if they don't exist in the source object, how to do this is detailed in the link provided.

Answer (score 3):

It can easy be done using Object.assign() method -

```
 var object1 = {name: "John"};
 var object2 = {location: "San Jose"};
 var object3 = Object.assign(object1,object2);
 console.log(object3);
```

now object3 is { name: 'John', location: 'San Jose' }

Comment: In your example, `object1` is also modified. [Check my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37336592/36272) for more details.

Answer (score 2):

If you need special behaviors like nested object extension or array replacement you can use Node.js's [extendify](https://www.npmjs.org/package/extendify).

```
var extendify = require('extendify');

_.extend = extendify({
    inPlace: false,
    arrays : 'replace',
    isDeep: true
});

obj1 = {
    a:{
        arr: [1,2]
    },
    b: 4
};

obj2 = {
    a:{
        arr: [3]
    }
};

res = _.extend(obj1,obj2);
console.log(JSON.stringify(res)); //{'a':{'arr':[3]},'b':4}
```

Comment: To be accurate: Extendify is not by Node.js. It is a package for Node.js.

Answer (score 2):

[Lodash](https://lodash.com) is a another powerful tool-belt option for these sorts of utilities.  See: [`_.merge()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.15.0#merge) (which is recursive)

```
var object = {
  'a': [{ 'b': 2 }, { 'd': 4 }]
};
var other = {
  'a': [{ 'c': 3 }, { 'e': 5 }]
}; 
_.merge(object, other);
// => { 'a': [{ 'b': 2, 'c': 3 }, { 'd': 4, 'e': 5 }] }
```

Answer (score 1):

The below code will help you to merge two JSON object which has nested objects.

```
function mergeJSON(source1,source2){
    /*
     * Properties from the Souce1 object will be copied to Source2 Object.
     * Note: This method will return a new merged object, Source1 and Source2 original values will not be replaced.
     * */
    var mergedJSON = Object.create(source2);// Copying Source2 to a new Object

    for (var attrname in source1) {
        if(mergedJSON.hasOwnProperty(attrname)) {
          if ( source1[attrname]!=null && source1[attrname].constructor==Object ) {
              /*
               * Recursive call if the property is an object,
               * Iterate the object and set all properties of the inner object.
              */
              mergedJSON[attrname] = zrd3.utils.mergeJSON(source1[attrname], mergedJSON[attrname]);
          } 

        } else {//else copy the property from source1
            mergedJSON[attrname] = source1[attrname];

        }
      }

      return mergedJSON;
}
```

Comment: this is the only correct, self-contained answer

Comment: Thank you! @lurscher

Answer (score 1):

You can use Lodash

```
const _ = require('lodash');

let firstObject = {'email' : 'email@email.com'};
let secondObject = { 'name' : { 'first':message.firstName } };
_.merge(firstObject, secondObject)
```

Answer (score 0):

A better approach from the correct solution here in order to not alter target:

```
function extend(){
  let sources = [].slice.call(arguments, 0), result = {};
  sources.forEach(function (source) {
    for (let prop in source) {
      result[prop] = source[prop];
    }
  });
  return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it inline, without changing any variables like this:

```
let obj1 = { name: 'John' };
let obj2 = { surname: 'Smith' };
let obj = Object.assign({}, obj1, obj2); // { name: 'John', surname: 'Smith' }
```

Answer (score -3):

Let `object1` and `object2` be two JSON object.

```
var object1 = [{"name": "John"}];
var object2 = [{"location": "San Jose"}];

object1.push(object2);
```

This will simply append `object2` in `object1`:

```
[{"name":"John"},{"location":"San Jose"}]
```

Comment: This isn't what the OP asked. You're showing how to build an array of JSON objects. The OP asked for a way to combine key:value pairs from multiple JSON objects into a single one.