# Node.js: Extend JSON object

Tags: json, node.js, extend

I would like to extend the native `JSON` object of node.js. In my example, I was able to extend it to add a `merge(json1, json2)` function, which merges 2 JSONs:

```
JSON.merge = function(target) {
    var sources = [].slice.call(arguments, 1);
    sources.forEach(function (source) {
        for (var prop in source) {
            target[prop] = source[prop];
        }
    });
    return target;
}
```

This script is larglely inspired from this question: [Combine or merge JSON on node.js without jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14974864/combine-or-merge-json-on-node-js-without-jquery)

To have a cleaner code, I put this script in a library folder, and require it in my main script. This is what I did...

My `lib/JSON.js` file:

```
extends.merge = function(target){
    // The same script as above.
}
```

and in my `app.js` file:

```
JSON = require('./lib/JSON')
```

It works well, but now, native JSON methods don't work (like `.stringify`). Then I digged a little bit, and tried to extend JSON using `.prototype`, like this (in `lib/JSON.js`):

```
extends.prototype.merge = ...
```

But get the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot set property 'merge' of undefined
```

I really don't know what to do (and what I'm doing) since solving a problems causes another problem.

Please, need help.

Thanks.

Comment: You are confusing JSON and JS objects. You are just dealing with the latter so leave the JSON module alone and put your merge function into some other module that is not named JSON (because naming it JSON would be wrong).

Comment: Thanks ThiefMaster, it works by changing the name (and it's less confusing). But is it possible to extend `JSON` (I read that `JSON` has only two methods: `.parse()` and `.stringify()`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_native_JSON?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Using_JSON_in_Firefox)?

Comment: Yey, name your module differently and simply add the functions to `JSON`, i.e. `JSON.foo = function() {...};`

Comment: Thank you ThiefMaster, your comment solved my problem. Can you add it as an answer to close the question? Thanks.