# Node.js bodyparser cannot ready AFNetworking POST array

Tags: objective-c, json, node.js, http, afnetworking-2

I am trying to post a JSON message which contains an array to my server. However the server is unable to identify the elements in the array. After inspecting the issue I have come across what I believe is the problem.

AFNetworking code:

```
AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [[AFHTTPSessionManager alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:kServiceBaseUrl]];
manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];

[manager PUT:@"/api/createRubaway"
   parameters:myDictionary
      success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, NSDictionary *responseObject)
     {/* stuff */}
      failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, NSError *error)
     {/* stuff */}
 ];
```

LLDB print out of 'myDictionary':

```
{
    description = description;
    title = title;
    transitions =     (
                {
            idx = 0;
            resource =             {
                data = testdata;
                name = transition;
                type = image;
            };
            threshold = "0.75";
            type = rubaway;
        },
                {
            idx = 1;
            resource =             {
                data = testdata;
                name = transition;
                type = image;
            };
            threshold = "0.75";
            type = rubaway;
        }
    );
}
```

After AFNetworking has serialized the request. If I print out the HTTPBody from the NSMutableRequest, this is what it is sending (this is what is being sent to my server):

```
description=description&title=title&transitions[][idx]=0&
transitions[][resource][data]=testdata&
transitions[][resource][name]=transition&
transitions[][resource][type]=image&
transitions[][threshold]=0.75&
transitions[][type]=rubaway&transitions[][idx]=1&
transitions[][resource][data]=testdata&
transitions[][resource][name]=transition&
transitions[][resource][type]=image&transitions[][threshold]=0.75&
transitions[][type]=rubaway
```

Is the above formatting correct. As my server (Node.js - BodyParser) I believe is expecting it in this format https://stackoverflow.com/a/18402556/623750

Is there a way to change the formatting of the JSON serializer?. Alternatively is there a way to configure BodyParser to accept the above formatting?

Thanks,
Ryan

Comment: a question, in the nodejs code; what did you add as require('') to the file? I'm facing the same problem, the req.body is not recognised as an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do, to set requestSerializer to  `AFJSONRequestSerializer`, this will fix the issue.

```
 [manager setRequestSerializer:[AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer]];
 [manager setResponseSerializer:[AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer]];
```

Comment: Ah. I forgot to set the request serializer. Thanks, works great!

Comment: req.body is equal to the afnetworking response object. If you want an array then: req.body = ['test','test2'];