# combining two dictionaries: perl "hashrefslice" syntax in javascript?

Tags: node.js, perl, dictionary, hashmap

I have separate config files that are separate because one contains passwords and other sensitive data, and one that I don't mind the world seeing. So let's say I have:

```
sensitivedata = { password : 'foobaz', hostname : 'quux' };
globalconfig  = { timeout : 86400, port : 5190 };
```

and I want `globalconfig` to have the fields `password` and `hostname`. I can just do:

```
globalconfig.hostname = sensitivedata.hostname;
globalconfig.password = sensitivedata.password;
```

but this is tedious when there are lots of fields. Being a perl programmer, I want to do something like this:

```
@{ $globalconfig }{ keys %{ $sensitivedata } } = 
    @{ $sensitivedata }{ keys %{ $sensitivedata } };

# or ...

@{ $globalconfig }{ qw{ password hostname } } = 
    @{ $sensitivedata }{ qw{ password hostname } };
```

this could be done with `map` just as well, but this is precisely what we have the hashrefslice syntax for in perl. Is there a one-statement way to map a bunch of fields from one dictionary into another?

It occurs to me as I write this that I could also do this in perl:

```
subname( { %$globalconfig, %$sensitivedata } );
```

…which joins the two hashes into a new anonymous hash for purposes of passing their arguments, but I am not sure how to "dereference" a dictionary/hash in javascript. This solution also combines both dictionaries without specifically referencing elements (if I, say, only want some but not all of `sensitivedata` in `globalconfig`).

Please be gentle; I don't mean to incite a "my language vs your language" thing. I like node a lot, I'm just trying to borrow idioms I am familiar with and write my code efficiently.

Comment: related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14974864/combine-or-merge-json-on-node-js-without-jquery

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe javascript provides a native way to do this; if you were not talking about server side, https://github.com/stephenlb/jquery-hashslice/blob/master/jquery.hashslice.js might meet your needs.

Answer (score 3):

If you happen to be using jQuery, there's a nice [extend](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/) function:

```
$.extend(globaldata, sensitivedata);
```

Otherwise I suppose you need to roll your own, but it isn't hard.  With a recent-enough version of Javascript, it's:

```
for (let [key, value] in Iterator(sensitivedata))
    globaldata[key] = value;
```

By the by, in Perl,

```
@{ $sensitivedata }{ keys %{ $sensitivedata } }
```

would be more clearly expressed as simply

```
values %{ $sensitivedata }
```

Comment: Quite right; I feel being a little pedantic there is clearer. As per usual, of course, there are myriad ways to do it.  I am actually using node and not jQuery.

Comment: If there is a library for use in node that provides similar capability to jQuery's .extend and .each, it would be nice to hear about it

Comment: You can use Underscore's extend method or built in util._extend. see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14974864/combine-or-merge-json-on-node-js-without-jquery

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get Iterator working in node.js, but I did find a workaround to Sean's answer.

```
for (var key in add_headers)
  http_headers[key] = add_headers[key];
```