# How can a module in node.js maintain state?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have two different js files that use the same module.

file1.js:

```
var mod1 = require('commonmodule.js');
mod1.init('one');
```

file2.js:

```
var mod2 = require('commonmodule.js');
mod2.init('two');
```

(both these files file1.js, file2.js are loaded inside my server.js file, they themselves are modules)

now in commonmodule.js:

```
var savedName;
exports.init = function(name)
{
    savedName = name;
}
exports.getName = function()
{
    return savedName;
}
```

I noticed that this savedName is always overridden dependent on who set it last.So it doesn't seem to work. How would I get a module to maintain state?

Note: I also tried to set savedName as exports.savedName in the commonmodule.js but it doesn't work either

Comment: No, because modules are cached so any changes will be effective everywhere. What is your question then? How to solve that? Just why?

Comment: yes, I want to know HOW I can maintain state inside a module

Comment: This is how state is `maintained`. Perhaps you wanted to ask how to get isolated state for each module?

Comment: Modules are effectively IIFEs and the variable as you have defined it is part of the IIFE's closure. @miguel-mota's solution works for your scenario because the variable has been defined within the `CommonModule` function and is thus part of that function's closure.

Answer (score 8):

You can just create a new instance every time the module is required:

commonmodule.js

```
function CommonModule() {
    var savedName;
    return {
        init: function(name) {
            savedName = name;
        },
        getName: function() {
            return savedName;
        }
    };
}

module.exports = CommonModule;
```

file1.js

```
var mod1 = new require('./commonmodule')();
mod1.init('one');
console.log(mod1.getName()); // one
```

file2.js

```
var mod2 = new require('./commonmodule')()
mod2.init('two');
console.log(mod2.getName()); // two
```

Comment: Why is the "new" keyword needed? Correct me if i'm wrong but functions doesn't store state but direct object does. so each time the function is ran then a fresh object will be returned from it.

Comment: @CarlosMiguelColanta you're correct the `new` keyword is not required in this example. If you use `this` or ES6 classes to maintain state then it would be required

Answer (score 6):

modules in and of themselves are  simple object instances. A single instance will be shared by all other modules (with the caveat that it is loaded via the same path). If you want state, use a class and export a constructor function.

example:

```
//Person.js
function Person(name) {
    this.name = name;
}

module.exports = Person;
```

To use it:

```
var Person = require("./Person");
var bob = new Person("Bob");
```

Answer (score 0):

Modules are not like classes/class functions; by default, `mod1` and `mod2` will refer to the same module due to caching. To keep track of per-instance state, you'll need a constructor function or something similar inside your module, e.g.

```
var mod = require('commonmodule.js');
var state = new mod.init('one');
```

Where `init` defines the stateful object. You could also have it return an object literal, in which case you wouldn't have to use `new` (e.g. `var state = require('commonmodule.js').init('one');`)

(This is assuming you want the module to have other, shared state in addition to the per-instance state; if that is not the case, Peter Lyons' method would be simpler.)

Comment: so I would have to pass this 'state' into every function I use in this module right? (as the module depends on state)

Answer (score -2):

You could perhaps remove from cache your module. Like that:

file1.js:

```
var mod1 = require('commonmodule.js');
mod1.init('one');
```

file2.js:

```
delete require.cache[require.resolve(modulename)];

var mod2 = require('commonmodule.js');
mod2.init('two');
```

But I don't find it very convenient and clean.

But you could also [clone it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5055746/cloning-an-object-in-node-js) or make a small proxy.

Also you could create classes:

```
var savedName;
exports.obj = {}
exports.obj.prototype.init = function(name)
{
    savedName = name;
}
exports.obj.prototype.getName = function()
{
    return savedName;
}
```

Then :

```
var mod2 = new (require('commonmodule.js'))();
mod2.init('two');
```