# Express.js - Setting res.locals changes the req object

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, locals

I am very confused what is about happening here. I am trying to set a res.locals default profile picture for a user if they do not currently have one. Here is my code:

```
// Make user object available in templates.
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.locals.user = req.user;
  if (req.user && req.user.profile) {
    console.log('Request Picture: ', req.user.profile);
    res.locals.user.profile.picture = req.user.profile.picture || defaults.imgs.profile;
    console.log('Request Picture After Locals: ', req.user.profile);
  }
  next();
});

// Console Results
Request Picture:  { picture: '',
  website: '',
  location: '',
  gender: '',
  name: 'picture' }
Request Picture After Locals:  { picture: '/img/profile-placeholder.png',
  website: '',
  location: '',
  gender: '',
  name: 'picture' }
```

I want to be able to write JADE without having to handle something like this: `img(src=user.profile.picture || defaults.profile.picture)`. So the above code works fine in all of the JADE views.

But, I need to check the `req.user.profile.picture` somewhere else in order to change the picture.

`if (!req.user.profile.picture) {do stuff}`

As you can see above the `req` has been changed. Setting `res.locals` should not change the `req` object...correct!? Or am I missing something?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Objects in Javascript are assigned by pointer.  So, when you do this:

```
res.locals.user = req.user;
```

You now have both `res.locals.user` and `req.user` pointing at exactly the same object.  If you then modify that object through either one, both are pointing at the same object so both will see the change.

Perhaps what you want to do is to COPY the `req.user` object over to `res.locals.user` so you have two completely separate objects that can be modified independently.

There are various mechanisms for copying (or cloning) an object in node.js shown here:

[Cloning an Object in Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5055746/cloning-an-object-in-node-js)

There is also [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)

Comment: Oh wow...I can't believe I missed that. Here I am thinking this is an Express thing when it is a simple JS thing. That is such a "gotcha" in JS.
Thanks for the help! Answer accepted.