# _extend property in 'util' node module

Tags: node.js

In one of the node examples , I came across below line

```
const extend = require('util')._extend;
```

Can anyone explain whats the purpose of _extend method of 'util' node module ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Low-frills deep copy:

```
var obj2 = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj1));
```

For a shallow copy, use Node's built-in util._extend() function.

```
var extend = require('util')._extend;

var obj1 = {x: 5, y:5};
var obj2 = extend({}, obj1);
obj2.x = 6;
console.log(obj1.x); // still logs 5
```

Source code of Node's _extend function is in here: https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/lib/util.js

```
exports._extend = function(origin, add) {
// Don't do anything if add isn't an object
if (!add || typeof add !== 'object') return origin;

  var keys = Object.keys(add);
var i = keys.length;
while (i--) {
origin[keys[i]] = add[keys[i]];
}
return origin;
};
```

For more information you can follow [EXTEND](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5055746/cloning-an-object-in-node-js)

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Shallow copy as mentioned by Nitin above, it also combines the properties of the parameters passed

From the source code of util._extend

```
exports._extend = function(origin, add) {
// Don't do anything if add isn't an object
if (!add || typeof add !== 'object') return origin;

  var keys = Object.keys(add);
var i = keys.length;
while (i--) {
origin[keys[i]] = add[keys[i]];
}
return origin;
};
```

So it combines the properties of `origin` and `add` parameters from the above code snippet and returns the extended object.