# Cloning an object and changing values mutates the original object as well

Tags: javascript, object

I was wondering why does this happen?

I have an object stored in var myObj:

```
var myObj = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('json/data.json', 'utf8'));
```

then I take a clone from the original object by:

```
var modObj = myObj;
```

After that I remove empty values from clone:

```
cleansedObj = removeEmpty(modObj);
```

Why does this also mutate the original myObj and remove empty values from that too?

here is the function:

```
function removeEmpty(obj) {
  Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(key) {
    if (obj[key] && typeof obj[key] === 'object') removeEmpty(obj[key])
    else if (obj[key] === "") delete obj[key]
  });
  return obj;
};
```

I found a workaround by doing this, but seems like uneccesary operation:

```
var cleansedObj = JSON.stringify(myObj);
cleansedObj = removeEmpty(JSON.parse(cleansedObj));
```

Thanks!

Comment: `var modObj = myObj;` is not cloning, you are just passing the reference to `myObj` to `modObj`

Comment: Probably related (`fs.readFileSync` feels like Node): [Cloning an Object in Node.js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5055746/cloning-an-object-in-node-js)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I correctly clone a JavaScript object?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/728360/how-do-i-correctly-clone-a-javascript-object)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are not cloning you are just refering the same with new variable name.

Create a new object out of existing and use it

```
var modObj  = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(myObj));
```

Answer (score 4):

**You are not cloning**, you are just passing the reference to `myObj` to `modObj`.

You can use [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)

```
var modObj = Object.assign({},myObj);
```

> The `Object.assign()` method is used to copy the values of all enumerable own properties from one or more source objects to a target object. It will return the target object.

Answer (score 3):

You are not cloning ! :/

Replace this:

```
var modObj = myObj;
```

By this:

```
var modObj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(myObj));
```

If myObj is an array do this:

```
var modObj = myObj.slice();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use jQuery, then you can do this

```
var mobObj = jQuery.extend(true, {}, myObj);
```

else try this

```
var mobObj = Object.assign({}, myObj);
```

Comment: I don't think he can use jQuery. He's apparently reading local files, what implies no browser.

Comment: there is a jQuery npm package

Comment: I should have figured out... xD

Answer (score 1):

although `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(myObj))` may seem simple and tempting, especially for bigger data structures it is not, because it has to serialize the objects and then parse this string again. I'd reccomend something like this:

```
function clone(deep, obj=undefined){
    var fn = clone[deep? "deep": "shallow"] || function(obj){
        return (!obj || typeof obj !== "object")? obj:  //primitives
            Array.isArray(obj)? obj.map(fn):            //real arrays
            deep? 
                //make a deep copy of each value, and assign it to a new object;
                Object.keys(obj).reduce((acc, key) => (acc[key] = fn(obj[key]), acc), {}):
                //shallow copy of the object
                Object.assign({}, obj);
    };
    return obj === undefined? fn: fn(obj);
}
clone.deep = clone(true);
clone.shallow = clone(false);
```

and then

```
//make a deep copy
var modObj = clone.deep(myObj);
//or 
var modObj = clone(true, myObj);

//or a shallow one
var modObj = clone.shallow(myObj);
//or
var modObj = clone(false, myObj);
```

I prefer this style `clone.deep(whatever)` because the code is self explaining and easy to scan over.