# Node MySQL Pool Cluster Event Emitter Not Working

Tags: mysql, node.js, eventemitter

The [documentation](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#pooling-connections) gives examples of registering connection event emitters for pools:

```
pool.on('connection', function (connection) {
    connection.query('SET SESSION auto_increment_increment=1');
});
```

Documentation shows how to get a pool from a cluster:

```
var pool = poolCluster.of('SLAVE*', 'RANDOM');
pool.getConnection(function (err, connection) {});
pool.getConnection(function (err, connection) {});
pool.query(function (error, results, fields) {});
```

However, `var pool = poolCluster.of('SLAVE*', 'RANDOM');` followed by `pool.on( ... )` errors with `pool.on is not a function`

Trying to register the `.on('connection')` via the cluster executes without error but has no effect.

Code to reproduce:

```
var mysql = require('mysql');

var mysql_pool_cluster = mysql.createPoolCluster();
mysql_pool_cluster.add('myPool', {user: 'root', password: 'password'});
mysql_pool_cluster.on('connection', function(new_conn) {
    console.log('hello from cluster event emitter');
    new_conn.release();
});

var pool = mysql_pool_cluster.of('myPool', 'ORDER');
try {
    pool.on('connection', function(new_conn) {
        console.log('hello from pool event emitter');
        new_conn.release();
    });
} catch(err) {
    console.error(err);
}

console.log('');

pool.getConnection(function(err, conn) {
    if (err) {
        console.error(err);
    } else {
        console.log('hello from new connection');
        conn.release();

        mysql_pool_cluster.end(function(err) {
            if (err) {
                console.error(err);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Output from above code:

```
TypeError: pool.on is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (E:\scratch\scratch_server.js:14:7)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:604:10)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:394:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:149:9)
    at bootstrap_node.js:509:3

hello from new connection
```

As you can see, `pool.on('connection')` fails to execute, and `cluster.on('connection')` does not emit when running for the first time `.getConnection()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided that the cluster library was not up to spec, so I coded my own cluster class:

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
var Promise = require('promise');

var deepCopy = function(obj) {
    // https://stackoverflow.com/a/15040626
    return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj));
};
var logger = {log: console.log, error: console.error};

class mysqlPoolCluster {
    // custom class to work around event emitter bug in mysql.createPoolCluster()
    //  https://stackoverflow.com/q/44466894

    constructor() {
        this._pool_dict = {};
        this._future_pools_on_events_dict = {};
    }

    mergeAndSplitConfs(segregated_confs_dict) {
        /*
            Converts this object --
            {
                pools: {
                    admin: {connectionLimit: 1, user: 'my_admin', password: 'password'},
                    read: {user: 'my_reader', password: 'password'},
                    write: {user: 'my_writer', password: 'password'},
                    read_write: {user: 'my_reader_writer', password: 'password'}
                },
                host: 'localhost',
                database: 'my_db',
                connectionLimit: 2
            }

            to this object --
            {
                admin: {
                    connectionLimit: 1,
                    user: 'my_admin',
                    password: 'password',
                    host: 'localhost',
                    database: 'my_db'
                },
                read: {
                    connectionLimit: 2,
                    user: 'my_reader',
                    password: 'password',
                    host: 'localhost',
                    database: 'my_db'
                },
                write: {
                    connectionLimit: 2,
                    user: 'my_writer',
                    password: 'password',
                    host: 'localhost',
                    database: 'my_db'
                },
                read_write: {
                    connectionLimit: 2,
                    user: 'my_reader_writer',
                    password: 'password',
                    host: 'localhost',
                    database: 'my_db'
                }
            }
        */

        var pools_dict = deepCopy(segregated_confs_dict.pools);
        if (!pools_dict) {
            throw new Error("arg does not have property 'pools'");
        }

        var base_conf = deepCopy(segregated_confs_dict);
        delete base_conf.pools;

        var base_keys = Object.keys(base_conf);
        var pool_names = Object.keys(pools_dict);
        for(var i_pool_name=0; i_pool_name < pool_names.length; i_pool_name++) {
            var pool_conf = pools_dict[pool_names[i_pool_name]];
            for(var i_base_key=0; i_base_key < base_keys.length; i_base_key++) {
                var base_key = base_keys[i_base_key];
                if (!pool_conf.hasOwnProperty(base_key)) {
                    pool_conf[base_key] = deepCopy(base_conf[base_key]);
                }
            }
        }

        return pools_dict;
    }

    populatePools(confs_dict) {
        // 'confs_dict' is the return from this.mergeAndSplitConfs()
        var names = Object.keys(confs_dict);
        try {
            for(var i_name=0; i_name < names.length; i_name++) {
                var name = names[i_name];
                this.createAndAddPool(name, confs_dict[name]);
            }
        } catch(err) {
            this.endClusterAndRemovePoolsPromiser()
            .catch(logger.error);

            throw err;
        }
    }

    createAndAddPool(name, conf) {
        if (this._pool_dict.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
            throw new Error("pool '" + name + "' already exists");
        }

        this._pool_dict[name] = mysql.createPool(conf);

        try {
            this.getPool(name).on('connection', function(conn) {
                conn.queryPromiser = function(sql, args) {
                    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
                        conn.query(
                            sql,
                            args,
                            function(err, results, fields) {
                                if (err) {
                                    reject(err);
                                } else {
                                    resolve( {"results": results, "fields": fields} );
                                }
                            }
                        );
                    });
                };
            });

            var that = this;

            this.getPool(name).queryPromiser = function(sql, args) {
                return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
                    that.getPool(name).query(
                        sql,
                        args,
                        function(err, results, fields) {
                            if (err) {
                                reject(err);
                            } else {
                                resolve( {"results": results, "fields": fields} );
                            }
                        }
                    );
                });
            };

            this.getPool(name).getConnectionPromiser = function() {
                return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
                    that.getPool(name).getConnection(
                        function(err, conn) {
                            if (err) {
                                reject(err);
                            } else {
                                resolve(conn);
                                // remember to call conn.release() when you're finished with the conn
                            }
                        }
                    );
                });
            };

            var events = Object.keys(this._future_pools_on_events_dict);
            for(var i_event=0; i_event < events.length; i_event++) {
                var event = events[i_event];
                for(var i_cb=0; i_cb < this._future_pools_on_events_dict[event].length; i_cb++) {
                    this.getPool(name).on(event, this._future_pools_on_events_dict[event][i_cb]);
                }
            }

            return this.getPool(name);
        } catch(err) {
            this.endAndRemovePoolPromiser(name)
            .catch(logger.error);

            throw err;
        }
    }

    getPool(name) {
        if (this._pool_dict.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
            return this._pool_dict[name];
        } else {
            throw new Error("pool '" + name + "' does not exist");
        }
    }

    endAndRemovePoolPromiser(name) {
        var that = this;
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            that.getPool(name).end(function(err) {
                delete that._pool_dict[name];

                if (err) {
                    reject(err);
                } else {
                    resolve();
                }
            });
        });
    }

    endClusterAndRemovePoolsPromiser() {
        var end_promises = [];
        var err_list = [];
        var names = Object.keys(this._pool_dict);
        for(var i_name=0; i_name < names.length; i_name++) {
            end_promises.push(
                this.endAndRemovePoolPromiser(names[i_name])
                .catch(function(err) {
                    err_list.push(err);
                })
            );
        }

        return Promise.all(end_promises)
        .then(function() {
            if (err_list.length) {
                return Promise.reject(err_list);
            }
        });
    }

    on(event, cb) {
        var names = Object.keys(this._pool_dict);
        for(var i_name=0; i_name < names.length; i_name++) {
            this.getPool(names[i_name]).on(event, cb);
        }

        if (!this._future_pools_on_events_dict.hasOwnProperty(event)) {
            this._future_pools_on_events_dict[event] = [];
        }
        this._future_pools_on_events_dict[event].push(cb);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  const { charset, timezone } = options;
  Object.keys(pool._nodes).forEach(key => {
    pool._nodes[key].pool.on('connection', (connection) => {
      if (timezone) connection.query(`SET SESSION time_zone = '${timezone}'`);
      if (charset) connection.query(`SET NAMES ${charset}`);
    });
  });
```